# TypeError: socket.emit is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to write basic online game, just to check my current level in web programming. Here is some code I have right now:

```
var io = require('socket.io') (serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('1 '+socket);
    function fight (player,monster) {
        console.log('2 '+socket);
        monsterData = {};
        monsterData.name = monster;
        switch(monster){
            case 'rat 1st level':
            monsterData.hp = 50;
            monsterData.attack = 1;
            monsterData.money = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
            break;
        }
        result = attack(player,monsterData);
        console.log('3 '+socket);
        if(result.winner === 'player'){
            db.account.findOne({'username':player.username},function(err,player){
                money = player.money + monsterData.money;
                db.account.update({'username':player.username},{$set:{'money':money}});
                socket.emit('addToChat',{type:'system',message:'You win battle against "'+monster+'"'})
            });
        }
    }
    console.log('4 '+socket);
    socket.on('click',function(data){
        db.account.find({'username':data.username,'socket':data.socket},function(err,res){
            if(res.length > 0) {
                position = 0;
                //console.log('x - '+data.x+'; y- '+data.y);
                            /* RIGH BAR */
                if(data.x>(1024-200) && data.x<1024 && data.y>80) {
                    // if(data.y>50&&data.y<80)
                    //  position=1; 
                    if(data.y>80&&data.y<110){
                        monster='rat 1st level';
                    }
                    if(data.y>110&&data.y<140){
                        monster='2ndMonster';
                    }
                    if(data.y>140&&data.y<170){
                        monster='3rdMonster';
                    }
                    if(data.y>170&&data.y<210){
                        monster='4thMonster';
                    }
                    db.account.findOne({'username':data.username},function(err,res){
                        db.account.update({'username':res.username},{$set:{'inFight':true,'monster':monster}});
                        io.sockets.emit('fightStart',{'username':res.username,'monster':monster});
                        result = fight(res,monster);
                    });
                    

                          /* /RIGHTBAR */
                }
                //console.log(position);
            }
        });
    });

    socket.on('signIn',function(data){                                                                  
        isValidPassword(data,function(res){                                                     
            if(res){                                                                                    
                db.account.find({'username':data.username},function(err,player){                        
                    player = player[0];
                    socket.emit('signInResponse',{
                        success:true,
                        username:player.username,
                        password:player.password,
                        level:player.level,
                        money:player.money,
                        hp:player.hp,
                        maxhp:player.maxhp
                    });   
                });

            } else {                                                                            
                socket.emit('signInResponse',{success:false,reason:'wrong login or password'});         
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So, basically, I can get socket variable in `socket.on('signin')`, but when I'm trying to get it in function fight or `socket.on('click')`, it gives me error that socket is not defined, or give me error because socket is just `socket.id` of client, with which I can't emit data.

## What I need

Some how to get variable socket accessible in fight function to have ability to emit data to specific player.

Comment: You used `io.sockets.emit` instead of `socket.emit` in the onClick handler.

Comment: yeah, but if i dont use it here, i will not be able to socket.emit because socket is socket.id of client. i send this pack to all user's just for now, but need to send it to specific, same with socket.emit('addToChat') in fight function

Comment: (Off topic) You had better get username with socket object that client data. In login : `socket.clientData = { username: player.username }`, and you can use it like this : `db.account.find({'username':socket.clientData.username}`.

Comment: It would be helpfull to know the output of the four `console.log(...)` statements. I'm not sure if  understood you well. It sounds like the variable does not contain the socket instance but the client id of the connected client. I can not believe in that from what I see ;-). But you declared a named function like a closure. Perhaps that's the problem. In that case the function is only declared once with the socket variable of the first connect from a client. If the client disconects the socket will be destroyed. Try `var fight = function( ...` instead of `function fight( ...` that might help.

Comment: console.log(1) is socket object that i need to emit data, console.log(4) is socket object too. But console.log 2 and 3 is just socket.id of client (string like 'tA7sAWGprFyilziZAAAA'

Comment: Yes, you've mentioned that in your question. But, I need to see the outputs of your log statement. To be more precise:  Please edit the Question and append the complete log texts for all client (or at least 2) concurrent client connections.  I would like to check if the client keys are the same of differ for the connection and if it is really the client id or just a different behavior of the toString-Method of the socket object.  Did you try to change the method declaration like I suggest? And what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use io directly:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('xxx', function(obj){
        io.emit('xxx', {xxx: xxx})
    })
})
```